# Cannot figure out what is wrong even though output is right

Tags: html

I need to recreate everything in this image exactly the same in HTML.
I have done so, but it says that the paragraph is missing, link is missing etc.

[Image to be recreated is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Egwhx.png)

My code so far is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>This page definitely has a title</title>
</head>
<body>
<font face = "Times New Roman">
<h1> <font size="5">This is some text!A level 1 heading with a tooltip that says 'tooltip' (with the quotes)</h1> </font>
<p><font size="3"><b>This level 3 heading has a link to <a href="https://www.ww3schools.com">https://www.ww3schools.com</a></b></p></font>
<p><font size="3">This is just a regular paragraph.</p>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I did not understand what is that you need exactly

Comment: The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5 - that's not a problem per se, but you seem to be closing them in the wrong order: `<p><font> ... </p></font>` should be `<p><font> ... </font></p>`

Comment: I suggest you use a code formatter on your code editor. formatting your code helps you avoid having mistakes like these as it aligns the opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your closing tags look to be in the wrong place,

Put the closing /h1 after /font

Your second line should be a h3 instead of a p, and put your closing /h3 after /font

On your third line put your closing /p after /font

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

@JakeBlack is correct, please accept his answer. My only extra input is, it helps to find these problems early, by properly indenting code so you can see what code blocks are encapsulating. Also no need for the extra HTML tag you had at the top.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>This page definitely has a title</title>
</head>
    <body>
    <font face="Times New Roman">
        <h1> 
            <font size="5">
                This is some text!A level 1 heading with a tooltip that says 'tooltip' (with the quotes) 
            </font>
        </h1> 
        <p>
            <font size="3">
                <b>
                    This level 3 heading has a link to <a href="https://www.ww3schools.com">https://www.ww3schools.com</a>
                </b>
            </font>
        </p>
        <p>
            <font size="3">
                This is just a regular paragraph.
            </font>
        </p>
    </font>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>This page definitely has a title</title>

<style>
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<p>This is some text!A level 1 heading with a tooltip that says 'tooltip' (with the quotes)</p>
<p>This level 3 heading has a link to <a href="https://www.ww3schools.com">https://www.ww3schools.com</a></p>
<p>This is just a regular paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```